# ImageView: onDraw method draws "behind" the image background, not at the top

Tags: android, imageview, ondraw

Here is the code of a simple extension of an ImageView that allow the user to draw with the finger.

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Point point : points) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
            // Log.d(TAG, "Painting: "+point);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = event.getX();
        point.y = event.getY();
        points.add(point);
        invalidate();
        Log.d("", "point: " + point);
        return true;
    }

    class Point {
        float x, y;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return x + ", " + y;
        }
    }
}
```

This work pretty well.

Now, I want to use this code to draw at the top of a Bitmap.

I used:

```
MyImageView ivPic = (MyImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
ivPic.setImageBitmap(picture);
```

But the drawing is drawn "behind" the Bitmap:

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can draw at the "top" of the Bitmap?

Comment: Have You managed to get a bitmap with your drawings and your bitmap behind ? i am doing the same and cant get to save the altered bitmap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed the order in `onDraw` method, I put `super.onDraw(canvas);` at the beginning and I think it works now

Answer (score 3):

override and use [dispatchDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) Method,  i used it to draw over views

Comment: Mosh do you still remember this? what do you put in the overriden dispatchDraw method?

Comment: You my friend saved my week right now. Thanks a lot. I used that on a RecyclerView and it worked perfectly. From API > 23 the is a method onDrawForeground(Canvas canvas) that does exactly that. But I am supporting API >= 16.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, just found the answer:

```
ivPic.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),picture));
```

Don't know if that's the best practice but that works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequence: first super.OnDraw(canvas) then your paint stuff

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Point point : points) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
            // Log.d(TAG, "Painting: "+point);
        }
    }
```